# Android - What does MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN -1 ussually means

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

I'm developing an Audio Player (using the MediaPlayer) which works fine on mdpi, hdpi, tablets, but throws a error: MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN -1 on Samsung Galaxy mini (ldpi).

What I noticed is that this error occurs for majority of songs, though there are 1, 2 songs that still plays on Galaxy Mini.

Why does this error usually occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to know what was the problem by passing the same URI that was causing the issue to the native Audio Player and let see how it will react. The native audio player responded in a more user-friendly way, by saying that the file type is not supported.

So at least now I know the problem is not from my side.

```
private void startNativeAudioPlayer() {

        String path="http://..";

        Intent intent = new Intent();  
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "audio/*");  
        startActivity(intent);
}
```